# Why is NA greater than an integer?

Tags: r, comparison, na, missing-data

I have looked at an old question that discusses how to find the `psum`. I used the data in that question to gain a better understanding of the `pmin` and `pmax` functions.
The data:

```
x = c(1,3,NA,5)
y = c(2,NA,4,1)
```

Now, running `pmax(x,y)` returns:

```
2 NA NA  5
```

while I expected 3 and 4 instead of `NA`s. 
Running `pmin(x,y)` on the other hand returns:

```
1 NA NA  1
```

The question is: Why is `NA` considered greater than 3 and 4 in `pmax`?

Comment: It is not grater or lower.  Any number with NA returns NA.  THat is the reason there is `na.rm` argument in `pmin/pmax`

Comment: I don't think it is considered greater than 3 or 4 but anything when compared to `NA` is `NA`. Try `NA > 5`, `NA < 5`, `NA == 5`.

Comment: The result of `pmin()` is in contradiction to your opinion that *NA considered greater than 3 and 4* ! ... or your opinion is in contradiction to the result.

Comment: @jogo right, I thought of it the other way round. I had simply focused on 3 and 4. Thanks all.

Comment: A return value `NA` means "I don't know". Since an `NA` value could be anything, a comparison with `NA` also returns an unknown value.

Comment: Even If you do `NA == NA`, the result is still `NA`

Comment: A nice quote which have saved the mental health of several of my students when struggling with computations and comparisons with `NA`: ["think of `NA` not as a number, but as a **placeholder** for a number that exists, but whose value we don't know"](https://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2016/07/understanding-na-in-r.html). And of course, see [R Language Definition on `NA` handling](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#NA-handling)

Comment: I agree. Those links have certainly taught me a lot. Thanks to all!

Comment: Also `?Comparison` is relevant reading: "Missing values (`NA`) and `NaN` values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in `NA`."